# More Searchfilters in AuthLDAPURL

Tags: apache-2.2, search, filter, mod-auth-ldap

Is it posible to have more then one searchfilter in AuthLDAPURL?

Example uid filter:

```
<Location /test/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Test"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://example.test.com/o=test,c=com?uid
        AuthLDAPBindDN "******"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ******
        require ldap-group cn=group01,o=test,c=com
</Location>
```

We need to search for uid or mail. Like...

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://example.test.com/o=test,c=com?uid|mail
```

**Solution** (it works for me):

Tested with Apache 2.4
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-uid>
    AuthLDAPBindDN "******"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ******
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://example.test.com/o=test,c=com?uid??(&(isMemberOf=cn=group01,o=test,c=com))"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-mail>
    AuthLDAPBindDN "******"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ******
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://example.test.com/o=test,c=com?mail??(&(isMemberOf=cn=group01,o=test,c=com))"
</AuthnProviderAlias>


<Location "/test/">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Login with mail or uid"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap-uid ldap-mail
    LDAPReferrals Off
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Thx Tonin!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you mean to look for attribute `uid` or `mail` (not filtering on those).  It is not possible, straight away, to use 2 different attributes in the LDAP URL, although [RFC 2255](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2255) allows for it.

### mod_authnz_ldap alone: not possible

Apache [mod_authnz_ldap documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl) states the URL must be like: `ldap://host:port/basedn?attribute?scope?filter` with

- **attribute**: The attribute to search for. Although [RFC 2255](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2255) allows a comma-separated list of attributes, **only the first attribute will be used, no matter how many are provided**. If no attributes are provided, the default is to use uid. It's a good idea to choose an attribute that will be unique across all entries in the subtree you will be using.
- **filter**: A valid LDAP search filter. If not provided, defaults to (objectClass=*), which will search for all objects in the tree. Filters are limited to approximately 8000 characters (the definition of MAX_STRING_LEN in the Apache source code). This should be more than sufficient for any application.

### Using 2 providers with mod_authn_alias

However, adding another apache module, namely [mod_authn_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html), you can use 2 different LDAPURL as different authentication providers.  For this to work, you can add a new file (that'll include at the root of your apache configuration) containing:

```
# Different LDAP attributes to be used as login
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-uid>
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://example.test.com/o=test,c=com?uid
    AuthLDAPBindDN "******"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ******
</AuthnProviderAlias>
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-mail>
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://example.test.com/o=test,c=com?mail
    AuthLDAPBindDN "******"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ******
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

Then, in your `<Location>` statement, you use the following configuration:

```
<Location /test/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Test"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap-uid ldap-mail
    AuthUserFile /dev/null
    require ldap-group cn=group01,o=test,c=com
</Location>
```

This will first try to authenticate using the `uid` and if it fails, try using the `mail` attribute.  With this type of configuration, you can add as many different LDAPURL providers as you wish.

You have to be careful about one thing though, the LDAP search must **return a single value**, otherwise you'll not be sure which of the multiple entries will be used to check the password to.  To achieve that, you can use a scope (`one` instead of `sub`) or a search filter that will limit the number of entries returned.

The additional file must be added to your apache configuration outside the `<Location>` or any `<VirtualHost>` directives.  It must be included at the root level of your apache configuration.  And the `authn_alias` module needs to be activated, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. 
Yes, I'm looking for attribute uid or mail.
I tried with Apache 2.4, only the following configuration worked, and it's not what I need.
AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://example.test.com example.test.com/o=test,c=com?uid".
It's not possible to configure two LDAP-URL including basedn?attribute?scope?filter.
I think the multiple LDAP-URL will be used for the subject "failover".

Comment: Yes, you're right, the solution I first presented is only working with 2 ldap servers where you use the same attribute and filters.  Like you said, it is for a failover solution.  I now present another, better, solution.